Django extra actions to have detail-view with paramters
I have 2 extra actions in Django. I need to provide additional query param to it, shown below:
class MyViewSet(mixin.ListModelViewSet, RetrieveModelViewSet, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
  ....
  ...
  @action(detail=True, method=["get"])
  def abc(self, request, pk, name):
   ....

  # detail for abc
  @action(detail=True, method=["get"], url_path=r"abc/(?P<name>[A-Za-z\.]+)")
  def abc_detail(self, request, pk, name):
   ....

The above is not working when I call the API like: http://localhost:8000/employee/1/abc/xy.z, but if I append / at the end I get the result: http://localhost:8000/employee/1/abc/xy.z/
with request http://localhost:8000/employee/1/abc/xy.z I get:
{
    "detail": "Not found."
}

But when I make request http://localhost:8000/employee/1/abc/xy.z/ (appending / at the end) I get:
{
  "result": True,
  "data": []
}

Please let me help understand what is wrong here. This should work without appending any / at the end.
In short, want a detail view for extra action as well.

You can take a look here https://learndjango.com/tutorials/trailing-url-slashes-django#:~:text=Among%20Django's%20many%20built-in,to%20see%20this%20in%20action. For the appending slash in django.

This setting is by default True. I have not changed it. Browser is appending slash in case: http://localhost:8000/employee/1/ but not here: http://localhost:8000/employee/1/abc/xy.z why this is happening?

The browser isn't doing anything, django is doing a redirect and your browser is fetching a 2nd page.  Look at your network tab.  I'm not sure why the action isn't.  IMO neither should work with the slash, but should 404.  That's just my opinion though.

You got me curious, so I tested it.  It works exactly as expected on django 5.0.2 at least, /1/abc/xy.z redirects me to /1/abc/xy.z/.   I think you have another issue, since "not found" means SOMETHING tried to resolve the 1 to an employee and it wasn't found.  Override get_object() and debug from there?

@Andrew employee 1 is there, but the thing is I am having another extra action like: employee/1/abc/ and then after that I want detail for this employee/1/abc/xy.z/. This I think is creating the problem, which I am not able to solve.
